# Find a file in the directories that have been modified in the last hour

Tags: java, groovy

I have a very large file system with a folder structure that can be 4 levels deep.   I have a file (i.e. test.log) that can be anywhere in this folder structure. Rather than traversing through the entire folder structure recursively, I want to apply some selection and only search folders that have been modified in the last 4 hours.   How would I use the Groovy traverse to perform an operation like that?  Thanks

Comment: does my answer work? If it's ok, please accept it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay...was trying to implement the solution.   The problem that I am having is that the lastmodified attribute on the file is a long data type.   I am having problems converting the TimeCategory into the long data type so it can be used in the comparison.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Use `time` on date to compare it with `lastModified()`.

Comment: Did it finally work?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work (have no possibility to check):

```
import static groovy.io.FileType.*
import static groovy.io.FileVisitResult.*
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

currentDate =  new Date()
use( TimeCategory ) {
    before4hours = currentDate - 4.hours
}

def toTravserse = new File('<SOME_DIR>')
toTravserse.traverse(
        type         : FILES,
        maxDepth     : 4,
        nameFilter   : ~/test.log/,
        preDir       : { if (it.lastModified() < before4hours.time) return SKIP_SUBTREE },
) { println "Found: $it" }
```

Have a look at the [docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#traverse(java.util.Map,%20groovy.lang.Closure)).